# Pentaho upgrade project

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm new to pentaho, so I downloaded a portable version (PDI 7.1) and created a project, jobs and transformations. But now I need to use version 8.2  so Im installing it, does my project in 7.1 need to be changed somehow? how do I upgrade it to the 8.2 version of pentaho? I have tried searching for configurations that indicate the version inside the project but couldn't find any. Is pentaho backwards compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your existing project from within the new version of PDI.  Your project should be OK, barring any inconsistencies between your PDI versions (plugins loaded, deprecated steps, etc.)